# Email based on value of report

Tags: linux, bash, email, debian-jessie, tripwire

I'm looking to grep a numeric value from a tripwire report, and if the value is greater than 0, send an email. The script so far looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tripwire --check > /tmp/twreport

count=grep 'Total violations found: 0' /tmp/twreport 

if [ $count < 1 ]; then
  mail -s "[tripwire] Report for `uname -n`" user@example.com < /tmp/twreport
fi
```

Not sure how to grab the value and set it as a variable or if there's a way to include it in the if statement itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First count the entries:

```
count=`grep -c 'Total violations found' /tmp/twreport`
```

Next step is simple, e.g. for more than 3 hits:

if [ $count > 3 ] ; then 
    mail -s "[tripwire] Report for `uname -n`" user@example.com

Comment: I had to put a `fi` at the end for it to work for some reason.